# Child-to-Parent Query - [object Object] is the result

Tags: soql

I'm trying to perform the following multilevel relationship query.

```
SELECT ID, SystemModstamp, Product__r.Catalog__r.Active__c 
FROM Journal__c     
WHERE SystemModstamp > 2013-10-02T00:00:00.000+0000 
AND SystemModstamp < 2013-10-05T00:00:00.000+0000
```

In the `Product__r.Catalog__r.Active__c` column I'm getting a value of `[object Object]` for every single record. I can substitute any field name from the `Catalog__c` object and get the same response. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to get the field's actual value?

Comment: No problem Danny :) What field type is the `Active__c`?

Comment: `Active__c` is a checkbox. I get the same result, however, using the `Name` field or `RecordType` field or any other field I put in there from the `Catalog__c` object.

Comment: Where is the query result used?

Comment: I'm performing the query in the Dev Console. It's part of a larger question of what caused 16000 Journal__c records to have their SysModstamp values all update last Friday morning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe this is currently a limitation or bug of the dev console. Trying to flatten a javascript object to a string returns the literal "[object Object]" you're seeing here, but would work for non-cross-object fields.

I've seen it before myself, but I've never had the time to open a support case about it, if you're able to it's certainly worth reporting it as an issue with the dev console.

In the meantime the query is perfectly valid and if you run anonymous apex like

```
System.debug(JSON.serialize([SELECT ID, SystemModstamp, Product__r.Catalog__r.Active__c 
FROM Journal__c     
WHERE SystemModstamp > 2013-10-02T00:00:00.000+0000 
AND SystemModstamp < 2013-10-05T00:00:00.000+0000]));
```

you should get a JSON representation of the query results in the debug log that you can work with in your text editor of choice (although you might want to run it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ for readability). 
Otherwise consider alternative tools like [force.com workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com/) of [SOQLXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/). Which can handle displaying cross-object query results.

Comment: I'd call it a limitation, I suppose. Not really a bug, or you'd get some silly error message, right? That aside, you can probably flatten the query as well (the point of using dev console query would be to possibly edit/view the records directly).

Comment: @sfdcfox I wouldn't really expect an error - they're probably building the columns from all the properties of the result object, and if you do that without recursing into any fields that are objects you end up with [object Object] by calling toString() on the relationship field when trying to render the row. Javascript is weird.

Comment: Force.com workbench did the trick for me. I had to go into settings and check the box for "Allow SOQL Parent Relationship Queries", which it told me to do, but after that it worked a charm.

Comment: Yes, known "limitation" with the dev console just like subqueries show the raw json, along with others. We have stories to improve the query view in the dev console but they are not high priority. The more feedback like this and more query editor traffic will help us prioritize in the future.

Comment: For those who don't know @Thomas is one of the developers behind the dev console. Thanks fro stopping by!

Comment: If you run the query via the command line you can ask for JSON output `sfdx force:data:soql:query --resultformat=json --query "SELECT ID, SystemModstamp, Product__r.Catalog__r.Active__c FROM Journal__c WHERE SystemModstamp > 2013-10-02T00:00:00.000+0000 AND SystemModstamp < 2013-10-05T00:00:00.000+0000"`

Comment: Oh its a bug 100%.  It doesn't return expected values nor the same values as if you run the query in another context.  I don't get why making the primary tool SF developer are forced to use function in a reasonable way would be a low priority.  Not everyone can move to DX...

Answer (score 3):

Can you try Anonymous Apex and try to print out the list in Debug Logs?

```
List< Journal__c> journeyList = [SELECT ID, SystemModstamp,Product__r.Catalog__r.Active__c 
FROM Journal__c LIMIT 10];
System.debug(journeyList);
```

Comment: I've tried this and got a result with all field valued just ok.

Comment: Where would you enter the anonymous apex code?