# Optimize code for fetching Account hierarchy in loop

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm using below code for fetching associated accounts when any account is deleted to update its parent account. I'm looping thru account hierarchy to identify top parent. Below is the code

```
    public static void getChildAccountsInHierarchy(List<Id> lstparentAcctId) 
    {
  try{
    Boolean endTraversing = false;
    Integer accountLevel = 0;
    String Query;
List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
parentIdList.add(lstparentAcctId[0]);

   while(!endTraversing) {
    
    if(accountLevel == 0) {
       query = 'select Id,Name, ParentId,Ultimate_Parent_Name__c,txt_Ultimate_Parent_Name__c,Ultimate_Parent_Id__c,txt_Ultimate_Parent_Id__c from Account WHERE Id IN :parentIdList';
    } else {
       query = 'select Id, Name, ParentId,Ultimate_Parent_Name__c,txt_Ultimate_Parent_Name__c,Ultimate_Parent_Id__c,txt_Ultimate_Parent_Id__c from Account WHERE ParentId IN :parentIdList';
    }
 
  acctList = Database.query(query);
    
    if(acctList.size() == 0 ) {
       endTraversing = true;
    } else {
               parentIdList.clear();
               Account a;
               for(Integer i = 0; i < acctList.size(); i++ ) {
                   a = acctList.get(i);
                   parentIdList.add(a.id);
                   accountDetailsMap.put(a.id,a);
                   lstUpdateUltimateParent.add(a);
                   }
                   accountLevel++;
          }
}
if(accountDetailsMap!=null)
{
    if(lstUpdateUltimateParent!=null && lstUpdateUltimateParent.size()>0)
    {
        Account Acct = accountDetailsMap.get(lstparentAcctId[0]);
        for(integer i=0;i<lstUpdateUltimateParent.size();i++)
        {
            Account objAcc= lstUpdateUltimateParent[i];
            ObjAcc.txt_Ultimate_Parent_Id__c=acct.Ultimate_Parent_Id__c;
            ObjAcc.txt_Ultimate_Parent_Name__c=acct.Ultimate_Parent_Name__c;
            updateAccountList.add(ObjAcc);
        }
    }
}
update updateAccountList;
}
Catch (Exception e)
{
    System.debug('ERROR:' + e);
}
}
```

As you see, to fetch the parent I have written a while loop which exits only when there is no parent (i.e. ultimate parent is found). Though this code gives the right result but executing query in loop is not the right way.

Is there any way this code can be optimized and the query can be out of loop ? Please suggest

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You can query [5 levels of parent records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/124311/accessing-grandparent-through-soql) (and as of 2023 [5 levels of child records](https://techsavvyamir.medium.com/nested-queries-parent-to-child-relationships-in-soql-queries-38ca1a0475f7) but see Derek F comment below that Apex not supported) in a single query via SOQL relationships.

So if the parent field is called `Parent__c` the query can be:

```
select
    Parent__c,
    Parent__r.Parent__c,
    Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__c,
    Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__c,
    Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__r.Parent__c
from ...
```

This reduces the number of queries in the loop by a factor of 5 but a loop is still needed for deep hierarchies. And the code is more complicated to write. If the depth is typically small, I'd stick to the simpler code.

Comment: A note on querying down 5 levels. That's still not available for use in Apex, only through API calls. The link does end up saying that, but having it here as a comment is good too.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make working with hierarchies a bit easier for this kind of scenario, and that is to create a custom field to represent the identifier for the ultimate parent account in the hierarchy.

This way, whenever you need to modify something in a hierarchy, it won't matter how deep it is, you may query every record that shares the same value in that field. You will also issue a single query in your code, and you would be able to query multiple hierarchies this way too (you could let the query order the results based on that field, for example).

To do this you would have to set up this logic in flows or triggers, however. But it would ease your work with the problem you described.