# Why am I getting [object Object]?

Tags: soql

We have the following tree. Contact.BOG_Committee__c.BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c

On BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c , I want the contact name.

When I put BOG_Membership__r.Contact__r.Full_Name1__c in my SOQL query which is querying BOG_Committee_w_Membership__c  I get "[object Object]" and not the actual contact name. Why?

FYI, Full_Name1__c is a formula field just concatenating first and last name.

Comment: I think you will find this question has already been asked and answered on SFSE: [Child-to-Parent Query - \[object Object\] is the result](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/child-to-parent-query-object-object-is-the-result)

Comment: It is and thank you. This may seem like a dumb question but when one enters a duplicate question there is usually a bunch of people who mark it a such? Isn't one person sufficient to do it or do you need a quorum of moderators to mark it that way?

Comment: One user can close as duplicate if they have the gold tag badge for any badge on the question. Otherwise it takes five.

Comment: thanks. Also, is it better to mark as duplicate and leave it or delete the question completely?

Comment: No need to delete unless it's drawing major downvotes. It can be useful actually to see the duplicate questions also.

Comment: Ok. Thanks my friend for answering my many questions. You're always a big help.