# Display Contact.RecordTypeId in Label through SOQL Query

Tags: soql, query, case, contact, record-type

I'm making a query on Case Object to capture the cases created for a certain span of time. In this query, I'm including columns from the related Contact Record, and one of the things I need to capture is the Record Type of the related Contact Record.

Now, the issue is that I can use Contact.RecordTypeId however, I want to return the Label of the Record Type instead. Is this possible?

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT Id, Contact.Id, Contact.Name, Contact.RecordTypeId
FROM Case
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using this. `SELECT Id, Contact.Id, Contact.Name, Contact.RecordTypeId,Contact.RecordType.Name FROM Case`

Comment: Hi @SaiPraveen - I was indeed doing this, but it only displays [Object object] when queried through DevConsole.

I did try it on Workbench and Dataloader, and RecordType.Name is indeed working.

Any explanation as to why it displays clunky in the Dev Console?

Comment: As it is referring from another object called Record type so it refers as [Object Object]. You can write some sample apex code and check if it is returning correct value or not as below. `list<Case> caselist=[SELECT Id, Contact.Id, Contact.Name, Contact.RecordTypeId,Contact.RecordType.Name FROM Case where id='5005j000008vTeVAAU'];
system.debug('liscase'+caselist[0].Contact.RecordType.Name);`

Comment: If you want to check in workbench you need to enable 'Allows SOQL Parent Relationship Queries' setting in workbench so you will be able to see the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can by using `Contact.Recordtype.Name`

```
SELECT Id, Contact.Id, Contact.Name, Product_Main_Group__c, Contact.Technology__c, Contact.RecordTypeId, Contact.Recordtype.Name FROM Case`.
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi @MohanRaj - I was indeed doing this, but it only displays [Object object] when queried through DevConsole.

I did try it on Workbench and Dataloader, and RecordType.Name is indeed working.

Any explanation as to why it displays clunky in the Dev Console?

Comment: In developer console, Yes. It's provide response as `object` notation. Please refer this it's will answer your question.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/child-to-parent-query-object-object-is-the-result